# selenium firefox webdriver can't load the profile

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am trying to use selenium on a flask server but I always get this error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpPKVQuH If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

This is the script and if I run it as root from a python shell everything works fine but the same script inside my flask app (who use the www-data user) does not work:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

As the script works fine from the shell I guess the problem is with something related to the www-data user but I am not really sure what could be.

Anyone has an idea how I could make it work?